# Unambiguous formal grammars for a specific class of languages

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automata

Suppose that $w \in \{0; 1\}^*$ is a binary word. Let's denote the number of $0$-s in $w$ as $\#_0(w)$ and the number of $1$-s in $w$ as $\#_1(w)$.

Now suppose that $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a positive rational number. Consider the language $L_q \subset \{0; 1\}^*$ of all words $w$, such that for any its prefix $p$ we have $\#_0(p) \leq q \#_1(p)$. For example, $L_1$ is the language of all possible prefixes of Dyck words.

It is not hard to see, that $L_q$ is deterministic context-free for any $q$. Indeed, if $q = \frac{m}{n}$ for some natural $m$ and $n$ we can build a following deterministic pushdown automaton that recognises our language. It has the following states:

State $0$: Reads an element from the input. If it is $1$, adds $m$ elements to the stack and remains in the State $0$. If it is $0$, moves to State $1$. This is both the initial state and the only final state.

State $i$ (for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$): Does not read input, but tries to read from the stack. If it succeeds, the stack has $1$ element less, and we transit to State $i+1$. If it fails because the stack was empty, we transit to State $-1$.

State $n$: Does not read input, but tries to read from the stack. If it succeeds, the stack has $1$ element less, and we transit to State $0$. If it fails because the stack was empty, we transit to State $-1$.

State $-1$: Reads input but does nothing. Nothing ever leaves this state.

Note, that this automaton is a final-state one. It stops when it attempts to read the input and finds that it has ended. It accepts the input if it stops in a final state.

From the fact, that $L_q$ is deterministic context-free we can conclude, that it is unambiguous. My question is:

> How can we explicitly build unambiguous formal grammars for $L_q$ for arbitrary $q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "unambiguous"?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, here is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar

Comment: Surely relevant: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51658/how-to-convert-pda-to-cfg

Comment: In your definition of $L_q$, do you have the further condition that if $w \in L_q$ then $\#_0(w) = \#_1(w)$? That is, in the _whole word_ the number of $0$'s and $1$'s is equal.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, no.

Comment: Please insert the push-down automaton, thanks.

Comment: @dan_fulea, I have added detailed descriptions of every state of the automaton to the body of the question.

Comment: No answer for this intriguing question? I'm unable to give one, but I'm opinion the question deserves an answer.

Comment: I don't understand the actual question... by "arbitrary $q$", in the last sentence, do you mean $q\in\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to rational $q$?  Or do you still mean rational $q$, but you're interested in explicitly building the grammar (as opposed to the PDA)?  If it's the latter, there are standard constructions going from a PDA to a CFG, right?  If it's the former, that's a more interesting question.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, I still mean rational $q$, but am interested in explicitly building an unambiguous grammar. I have now edited the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140743/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).